# Convention so represent string in .properties

Tags: language-agnostic, properties-file

If I have two properties:

```
foo=1
bar=2345
```

Is there a way to specify that `foo` is a number and `bar` is a string?

I assume: `bar="2345"` would do but I wonder if there's a widely accepted convention

Answer (score 1):

A properties file is a text file which contains data in some standard format, which can be read by the application using it. It is mostly used for configuration of the application and also for internationalization.

As per the wiki document https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

> Each parameter is stored as a pair of `strings`, one storing the name of
>   the parameter (called the key), and the other storing the value.

There is no way to specify / force the value to be `number` or `string` only (instead it is always a `string`). It is majorly the functionality of the framework / application which; while reading the properties file tries to parse the values. If it fails to parse the value (of certain specific type like `number`) it may fallback to some default value or will simply terminate the program.

Comment: @OscarRyz was the answer helpful to you?